# how to write a dockerfile and build a docker image?

Tags: docker

How to write a dockerfile and build a dockerimage. i would be grateful for a step by step instructions and illustrations if possible. i am new to usage of docker and we are using on linux platform.

Comment: You have many tutorials available online, for example: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/docker-explained-using-dockerfiles-to-automate-building-of-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First you have to install and configure docker in your local machine
2. Make directory for store docker file

   mkdir docker-test
        cd docker-test
3. Create docker file in your repository

   nano Dockerfile
4. Add follow line to Dockerfile

   FROM docker/whalesay:latest
       RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes
       CMD /usr/games/fortune -a | cowsay
5. Build docker file run follow command

docker build -t docker-whale .

If you want to further details about build process read full article [here.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_four/)

If you have any problem please comment.